# Electrical Panel Type

Tags: electrical-panel

What is the common name, as known in the construction industry / electrical trade, given for this type of a combination panel, Main 100 amp + Sub 70 amp.

One single strand aluminum wire is noted, as well as two different circuit breakers brand-names are noted.

The panel data plate is missing, however the house is built in mid 60' s in Southern California.

Thank you!
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you provide some close-up shots of this thing?

Comment: Where do the thickest wires come from?  Any chance they run along the top of the lower compartment, out of camera view?

Comment: Can you provide some close-ups of the lower compartment's breakers, as well as the main breaker in the upper compartment? That might help us ID this critter...

Comment: No, those are the only photos that were provided.  The compartment below the meter is also blocked-up.  Is there a name for this type of panel+sub design ?

Comment: @H1991 -- this is a very odd duck you've found here -- I haven't ever seen or heard of a split-bus meter-main, never mind one with two completely separate loadcenter sections.  If you can go back and get more pictures of the lower compartment + the upper compartment's main breaker, then we might be able to ID more about it (the upper compartment main *appears* to be a GE from the pics so far, but I'd need closeups to be at all sure)

Comment: In the 2nd pic from the bottom, there's a red wire with a bare end sticking up into space. At the very least put a wire nut on that bad boy! Sure, it's not connected to anything right now, but if/when someone's working in there, it could get bumped and pushed somewhere that it makes contact with something creating a circuit to who knows where and causing unknown havoc.

Answer (score 1):

### This appears to be a rather strange sort of "meter main" or "all-in-one" type of panel

The general type of panel you see here, with a meter socket, utility termination compartment, and loadcenter integrated into a single cabinet is called by various names: "meter-main", "meter-loadcenter", "all-in-one", or "CSED" (for Combination Service Entrance Device).  However, this appears to be quite an unusual device, even for its general type: most meter-loadcenter combinations have a single loadcenter interior, or a loadcenter interior and secondary main disconnect, not two separate loadcenters with separate (backfed) main breakers.  (This isn't a "split bus"/"rule-of-six" panel, either, as it appears both main breakers are fed separately from the metering compartment.)

As to the maker of this thing, my hunch is that this is a GE unit, based on the appearance of the upper half's main breaker; the general case style of that breaker resembles that of prior photos I have seen of older GE TQD(L) double-frame breakers, with the ridged front and single handle.  The general design of the neutral bars is also similar to those I have seen in pictures of older GE panels, as well.  However, it also seems to have suffered a terrible alien invasion of some sort, as the branch breakers in the upper half appear to be a mixture of Bryant/C-H BRs and Murray MPs.

Comment: I suspect it may originally have been a split-bus rule-of-six panel that was later reconfigured to feed each bus separately.  Note that the bottom half contains exactly 6 double-pole breaker spots, and the top half has a factory label of "light main".  I'm guessing if we could see inside the meter half there would be improperly double tapped lugs, from when someone moved the feeder for the top half from a breaker on the bottom to the meter lugs.

Comment: @NateS. -- that could very well be, but we need more photos (and labeling!) to tell for sure

Comment: I don't think we're gonna get labeling unfortunately -- in the first pic, you can see the outline of where the label used to be glued on the inner door.  It's long gone.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen them called "all in one" panels or even  what you mentioned, a "combi" panel. Not sure if there is a better trade name or lingo name for them.

At first I thought it was a Zinsco brand, in which case I would have called it a "fire started" panel. But looking closer at the pictures, I realize it's not!  Good!

Answer (score 0):

It's a "Meter/Main" panel, it also has a "Split Bus", probably because the upper section is the main house and you have a separate unit, an out-building with a sub-panel and/or sport court lighting on the property fed off of the 3 lower breakers. Nothing illegal about this from what we can see here.

The one wire that appears to be aluminum might be an older type of tinned copper wire, judging from the old cloth covering. If you turn the breaker off, remove the wire, and scrape the surface with a knife, you might see copper underneath.

Even if it is aluminum, as long as the breaker is marked as "Cu/Al" on it somewhere, it's fine. That is an old Bryant (Westinghouse) brand "twin" breaker. They are still made, but the current versions are now owned by Eaton and are all Cu/Al rated. But I don't know about the older original Bryant versions from the 60s. I can't read the label on your photo to see for sure. If the breaker is not Cu/AL, you could replace it with a new one just like it.